# How to perform background updates for a PWA news app

Tags: angular, progressive-web-apps, background-process

I'm working on an angular based PWA to display news articles. Is there currently any way for these to be fetched prior to the app being opened when installed on an android device? Periodic updates are a must so users with no signal aren't left reading really old data until they move back into an area with better signal or gain a wi-fi connection.

I've read about periodic sync but this seems quite new and not that well supported. Are there any other alternatives apart from making it a native application?

Answer (score 0):

You could make your own cache service in the application which caches the data on available internet and sync them into json format in an array.
And when the internet is off or connection is weak you get from this array.
And when internet is on it re-sync the data again in place of old cached data. And you could use service worker in order to get fast fetching performance.